How to find number of poles through commutation steps?
I powered up the Hall effect sensor with my controller and observed that my motor completes its six-step commutation in 90 degrees. To complete a 360-degree rotation, it takes 24 steps. How can I determine the number of poles through this observation?
and
I rotate the motor clock wise my commutation steps are
100, 101, 001, 011, 010, 110
Now please tell me how I can rotate motor. If you share sudo code that would be better for me to understand.

You are asking for a personal tutor, more or less. What works better here is having about 70-80% of the answer already, and arriving here with a very specific remainder that doesn't require a textbook worth of answer. At the very least, see if you can expand your question and provide more details. Please.

actually i am confused. because i dont have my motor documentation so i have no idea about it poles. i know how to rotate one pair pole motor. but i dont know how to know multi pole pair.


Three sensors correspond to three-phase motor, usually three windings & three pole pairs per 360 deg of "Electric angle".  2. One all-around step loop == 360 deg of "Electric angle". So, it looks like your motor have 234 = 24 poles


For finding the number of poles in the motor follow the following steps:
i.   Connect 2 phases to oscilloscope voltage probe and leave the third phase open.
ii.  Make one mechanical turn of motor by hand.
iii. Count the peaks of sinusoid obtained on the oscilloscope. The number of peaks will give you the number of poles in the motor.

In a very first approach each Hall sensor tells you if the corresponding coil connection (motor phase) should be connected to Motor VCC or to GND.
There is no situation, where all Hall sensors deliver LOW and no where all deliver HIGH. Accordingly the three driver outputs never provide all VCC or all GND at the same time.
So in a first experiment you can directly feed each driver phase input with the corresponding Hall sensor output and use a low, current limited supply voltage for the driver stage.
As an alternative you can use the full motor supply voltage and connect 3 high power resistors in series between the phase outputs and the motor coils to limit the current.
If the assignment between Hall sensor and motor phase is correct, the motor will spin. To invert the direction just invert all Hall sensor signals.
The rest of the month you will learn how to control the phase current using PWM and how to fine tune the commutation angle relative to the Hall sensor angle for optimal torque. There are several optimization strategies using different waveforms, e.g. sine or trapezoid.
The number of poles is not relevant for this approach.
